# SAT to knapsack vs. ETH

Tags: np-complete, satisfiability, knapsack-problems

Theorem states that every problem in $\mathsf{NP}$ can be reduced to another $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problem in polynomial time. Also you can only make a problem polynomially longer using polynomial time.

Thus SAT of length $n$ can be reduced to knapsack with length $n^k$ for some fixed $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$. We don't need to show that reduction, we only need to know that it exists.

Knapsack has quasipolynomial algorithm, in other words running time is $O(\alpha^{\log^p q})$ where $\{p,\alpha\}\in\mathbb{R}^+$ are some fixed numbers and $q$ is length of knapsack problem.

Now assuming we have converted SAT to knapsack we get runtime $O(\alpha^{\log^p n^k})=O(\alpha^{k^p\log^p n})=O(\beta^{\log^p n})$ where $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^+$ is some fixed number. So, the runtime is quasipolynomial.

Why doesn't this simply negate ETH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knapsack does not have any known quasipolynomial time algorithm (one which runs in
$n^{poly(\log n)}$ time, with $n$ being the inputs length).

What it does have is a [pseudo-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) time algorithm, i.e. an algorithm which requires polynomial time in the **numeric value** of the input, but exponential in the length of its description. The dynamic programming algorithm for knapsack runs in time $O(nW)$, however the input $W$ when given in binary representation requires $\log W$ bits, so the algorithm is actually exponential (and not quasipolynomial).

Comment: In fact no NP-complete problem has $o(exp)$ algorithm? $exp$ can be $2^{\sqrt n}$, of course.

Comment: If the exponential time hypothesis holds then the answer is no.